# Responsive contents on report for print and pdf export from ssrs paginated reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using one paginated report with some tables and charts
The chart (a bar chart) which shows details for few days [20-30 days]
The width of this chart is bit lengthy and the table contains the textual representation of the chart
The problem is the print preview and export to pdf the chart is getting splitted and the exported report is totally becomes unusable
How can we make the contents on an SSRS paginated report responsive on export and print

Comment: Could you not change it to landscape?

Comment: the chart and table is in same report . So if we change the report to landscape will it affects the tables as well?

Comment: Use Fit to Page (100%)?